# iOS in-App purchase types for my web pricing plans

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a web application which can be accessible only for paid users with monthly and yearly subscriptions.

When the user logs in, my web services will look for user subscription's details and reports user if the subscription gets expired.

I have been developing an iPad app for it with the above functionality. I would like to provide pricing plans in iPad app.
User subscription expiration can be done using my web service, apple does not need to let my app to know about subscription expiration.

Can I use In-App purchase to just make payments for the given pricing plans?
If so which type of purchase(consumable, non-consumable, auto-renewable purchase etc..) can be used?

Pricing plans looks like

$9.99 for 100 guests for 1 month

$19.99 for 300 guests for 1 month

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with non renewing products. Please check here some links...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html